# Why do people put the .env into gitignore?

Tags: git, laravel, gitignore

Laravel's official site recommends that we put the .env into gitignore and so to others.

Why? I feel it comes quite handy for future usage once you forget how you setup the configurations.

Comment: A hard lesson learnt doesn't need to be repeated. [My AWS account was hacked...](https://www.quora.com/My-AWS-account-was-hacked-and-I-have-a-50-000-bill-how-can-I-reduce-the-amount-I-need-to-pay). It is unfortunate that there isn't more visibility or protections from Github et al. Stay safe out there, and make security part of your devchain, especially as a hobbyist, or full-stack developer without devops support.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your `.env` file contains **very** sensitive information (your app key at the very least). You do **not** want this in version control where everybody can see this information and possibly use it to attack your site.
Think about database information which might be stored in there or email keys or passwords. Furthermore it is likely that the information which you use in your `.env` file also needs to change between environments so you will need to change values anyways.

What should you instead do?
Make a file `.env.example` in this file you place all the keys of your `.env`.
ex.

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=SomeRandomString
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Here you can see a file in which all the necessary information for somebody that wants to use your code is available but none of the sensitive information. Then somebody can copy this `.env.example` to `.env` and change the values.

Comment: But I have it in a private Repository, is it still a security issue there?

Comment: It is **really** bad practice to publish keys to versioncontrol. Unless there is a very strong reason to publish the keys. Do you know who can view all your version control files? What happens if your version control gets compromised. I do not believe that the "comfort" of publishing your keys weights up to the security vulnerabilities. You can never be 100% sure of security, this is an easy way to 'stop' an attacker. If somebody gets access to your version control he will at least not have your keys.

Comment: It is still best practice to not include it. If the same `.env` file works for both testing and production then that means you have other security problems because you're reusing passwords. The `.env` file should be environment specific.

Comment: How do you guys go about it? Just save all the sensitive data like Password, API-Keys, etc on your computer in an encrypted file?

Comment: On your own computer you save the information on an `.env` file which you create from the `.env.example`. This `.env` file does not get published to version control. When you pull your code elsewhere you create a new `.env` file from your `.env.example` for use on the server.

Comment: I don't save those at all. I get API keys from their respective websites when I need them. I also generate database credentials when I need them (or reset the password for an existing database user). For local development I use sqlite without any passwords at all or Homestead if I need mysql (the default passwords of which are already set in the default .env). For other credentials I use a password manager (keypassx, Lastpass, 1password, you choose.)

Comment: @stepbystep There are multiple ways you can do it. You can do the way milo described. That is pretty much guaranteed to work on any server. Alternatively you can configure the environment variables on the server level but how to do that varies depending on your set up.

Comment: @mniess you will need to store the credentials of your database in your production environment (or don't you?). The `.env` file is the best option for this. Same way your keys will need to be stored for usage by your site.

Comment: @milo526 exactly. I create them on a need-basis. When I need database credentials, I create them and add them to .env. When I need an API key, I log into the respective service, create it and add it to .env. I would NEVER save .env anywhere else though. It's just storing the credentials for the current environment.

Answer (score 9):

The answers here and many articles all said .env includes sensitive information so it should not be put in source control. But the thing is .env does not just include sensitive information, it may also contain typical setting configuration. You can just leave sensitive information out and keep all the other settings in git.

Some suggests put .env.example in git, I actually followed that for a while but found it quite “inconvenient”, especially for the guys who newly joined the team. When they check out the codes, they find codes can not run, then they just copy .env from other old guys (**not** from .env.example and make the necessary changes.) b/c for dev environment even the sensitive information like API key/DB password are shared.

Quite often the whole dev team will have one API key and one DB setting. I see this happened from time to time, which just makes me doubt the use of .env.example.

So now I use the practice of putting .env in git and put sensitive information in .env.local which is gitignored.

Ruby dotenv gem suggested this https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#what-other-env-files-can-i-use
Symfony 4 has also changed to [this behavior](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/dot-env-changes.html)
When I do nodejs project I also use a npm package called [dotenv-flow](https://github.com/kerimdzhanov/dotenv-flow#files-under-version-control) to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The `.env` file contains passwords and API keys that should not go into source control for security reasons. Plus they will likely change between environments (you should use different API keys for testing vs production)

What you can do is keep `.env.example.php` in git and keep it updated with the variables that need to be configured, but leave the value blank. Then on new install just do copy `.env.example.php` to `.env` and update the values for that environment.

Answer (score 0):

The List of files added in `.gitignore` file will be discarded by Git and will not be uploaded/downloaded to/from Git repository

Main advantages of putting `.env` in `.gitignore`.

1) The `.env` file contains sensitive information about the project. Information like your Database Credentials, You Encryption Key, If your app is using any API then you can have API Keys/Access tokens can be loaded from the `.env` file and you might not want those credentials to be accessible to everyone who has access to the project.

2) The `.env` file contains specific settings which you might not want to have same on Production and Development Environment

Eg. On Development Environment you may keep `APP_DEBUG = true` where as for Production it's recommended to have `APP_DEBUG=false`. Similarly if your app is using any API(Payment Gateway) then you will have to use Test API Credentials for Development Environment and Live Credentials(which will result in actual online transaction) for Production Environment which can be managed well through `.env` file.